# I tried to login visual studio Release Management client tool, login fails with "The current user does not have access to Release Management"

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, ms-release-management

I gave full permission(Allow) to Release Administrator in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online, Still am getting "The current user does not have access to Release Management".

Please see the attached screenshots.
Please give me some suggestion, how to fix this ? I tried Release Management server on-premise. It worked fine.

But only in Team Services am I facing this problem.

[image][image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Release Management Client is for Release Management Server, an older version of Microsoft's Release Management offering which was a totally separate installation and database. The client does not work against TFS/VSTS, it works against Release Management Server. You should not install Release Management Server, as it is being deprecated in favor of the new Release hub.

The security settings you're looking at are for the Release hub in TFS/VSTS web access.